# Using Laravel's Eloquent migration across databases

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, laravel

I have a database in PostgreSQL and I want to migrate to MySQL database but I want to quick answer on using the migration code for MySQL which was initially made for PostgreSQL.

Does my migration work on any database or just the database that I was running, in this case PostgreSQL?

Comment: Should work pretty fine, unless you're doing something that only MySQL or Postgre supports.

Comment: That is what I am talking about,forexample GIS extension in postgre,how could mysql handle that,anyway am not doing that

Comment: That may be a problem. Not sure if you can work your way around that one.

Comment: But what I want to know is if the migration codes can run on different databases, if don't use something specific can I run postgre migration of laravel on mysql,Oracle ..

Comment: Yes, you should be able to run it.

Comment: thanks, let me see then